# Is it possible to send cookies to ExternalEvaluate["WebDriver-Chrome"]

Tags: webdriver

I'm wondering if it's possible to send cookies with an ExternalEvaluate command to WebDriver-Chrome.  I am attempting to grab some data from a page that requires me to be logged in.  Additionally, the data I want is generated through a javascript request.

I have successfully set cookies and have accessed the page I need the data from using URLRead but the javascript is unexecuted using that method.

If it is not possible to use WebDriver-Chrome, I'm open to suggestions.

Maybe external evaluate to python and use selenium to grab the javascript data?

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: I have not tried this, but when you run `session = StartExternalSession["WebDriver-Chrome"]`, it starts a browser window, right? So you can do some things manually in the browser window, and some things by code using `ExternalEvaluate[session, ...]`. I think you can log in manually and then run your script.